# удаление строк содержащих определенные слова

Tags: grep

Есть команда `grep -vf стоп.txt file.txt > file2.txt` для удаления из `file.txt` строк, содержащих слова из файла `стоп.txt`.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы строки, содержащие стоп слово, но с заглавной буквы, тоже удалялись? Сейчас не удалиляются те строки, в которых стоп слово стоит в начале предложения и идет с заглавной буквы.

В списке стоп слов все слова написаны строчными.

Answer (score 1):

**Опция -i**

> --ignore-case 
>  Приказывает команде игнорировать регистр символов, таким образом, поиск будет производиться как среди заглавных, так и среди
>   строчных букв.

То есть нужно таким образом:

```
grep -vf -i стоп.txt file.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: почему то после добавления "-i" комп мне отвечает : grep: -i: No such file or directory

Comment: @Новичок добавьте в комментарий ваш запрос полностью

Comment: пишу точно так, как у вас. Без -i работает, с -i выдает ошибку

Comment: $ grep -vf -i minus.txt all.txt > all2.txt

Comment: grep: -i: No such file or directory

Comment: вы в корректной директории находитесь? Проверьте командой ls. И попробуйте пересоздать все 3 файла.